# WSO2 ESB task (scheduler) doesn't work

Tags: jms, wso2, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, wso2-esb

I have to send XML message to my jms proxy service (service receive and send back message over JMS) with ESB Task (scheduler).
I tried 2 solutions.

**1 solution**

In added task I fill:

```
message -> my XML
injectTo -> set 'proxy'
proxyName -> my proxy name
```

The result is that, my jms proxy receive the message but without JMS_Corelation (I guess the message is send local in ESB) and I get that error:

```
Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:432)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:321)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:255)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:198)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalResponder.handleResponse(LocalResponder.java:214)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalResponder.invoke(LocalResponder.java:111)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.RespondMediator.mediate(RespondMediator.java:23)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:255)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:198)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
```

If I send this message to queue, all workflow works fine, so it is well configure.

**2 solution**

In added task I fill:

```
message -> my XML
to -> my jms endpoint
format -> message format
```

The result is that, there is no result becasue nothing is happend. My jms proxy service doesn't receive any message.

Someone knows how to fix that?
Maybe there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JMS Proxy is configured to receive messages from a JMS queue or topic.

You should try to write a named sequence that send an appropriate message into your queue or topic. Then, configure your scheduled task to call this sequence :

- injectTo = sequence
- format = soap11 (for exemple)
- soapAction = mySoapAction (if needed)
- message = `<root>myMessage</root>`
- sequenceName = YourSequenceThatSendTheMessageToJMS