# Exception "Transport out has not been set" in Scheduled Tasks in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are working with ESB 4.9.
We have a simple pass-through proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
name="BankSeb1"
transports="https,http"
statistics="disable"
trace="disable"
startOnLoad="true">
<target>
 <outSequence>
 <send/>
</outSequence>
<endpoint>
 <address uri="https://server:port/bankas/seb"/>
</endpoint>
</target>
<description/>
 </proxy>
```

This service works properly and I don't have any problems.
But when I try to design a scheduled task for this service, the exception is thrown:

```
    TID: [-1234] [] [2015-12-08 15:25:32,943] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  
Connection:Keep-Alive,Date:Tue, 08 Dec 2015 13:25:32 GMT,Transfer-Encoding:chunked,
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:432)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

Scheduled task configuration:

```
 <task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
    group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="BankSeb">
    <trigger count="1" interval="10"/>
    <property name="injectTo" value="proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="proxyName" value="BankSeb1" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
        <root>
            <a>b</a>
        </root>
    </property>
</task>
```

The same task and service in ESB 4.8 works OK.
Could somebody help me to resolve this problem.
I tried such schema with several proxy services and always I get the same exception.

Comment: This problem was resolved by using properties OUT_ONLY and FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED . Depending on some parameter or element in input message we send or not a out message. Only one question remains: scheduled task in ESB 4.8 ignored out message, but in ESB 4.9 throws exception, why?

Comment: Would you please provide some code and or further description of the solution?  Thanks in advance!  Paul

Comment: It looks like that transport inherits from inSequence. If u use trigger there is no transport. I just use drop mediator when all work is done.

Comment: Please refer to following similar issue. There is a solution provided.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290847/wso2-esb-task-scheduler-doesnt-work